# Standard Deviation calculation error

Tags: python, math, standard-deviation

I am trying to figure out why this process gives me a wrong answer.

For [1,2,3,4,5] I am getting 1.2 instead of 1.414

```
def standard_deviation(number_list):
  average = sum(number_list) / float(len(number_list))
  stdev = 0
  for value in number_list:
      stdev += math.sqrt((average - value)**2) / float(len(number_list))
  return stdev

standard_deviation([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: Recheck the formula in your text.  Standard deviation will often divide by `len(number_list)-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implemented the formula incorrectly.

The definition is "The standard deviation is the square root of the average of the squared deviations from the mean."  [This numpy page explains it well (see the Notes section).](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)

The code `math.sqrt((average - value)**2)` doesn't do what you want; the sqrt and **2 sort of cancel each other out so the result is just `abs(average-value)`.

The numpy page succinctly describes the implementation as `std = sqrt(mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2))`.

The following correction to your code will work better:

```
def standard_deviation(number_list):
  average = sum(number_list) / float(len(number_list))
  sqdev = 0
  for value in number_list:
      sqdev += (average-value)**2
  sqdev = sqdev / float(len(number_list))
  return math.sqrt(sqdev)
```

Comment: Will sqdev += (average-value)**2 / float(len(number_list)) work on one line?

Comment: Yes, you can do a running average.  There are several ways to optimize the function depending on your goals.